# React Native elevation and position absolute

Tags: react-native, elevation

Trying to add `elevation` (shadow) to `View` works, however my second `View`, which renders circle, hides under `View` with `elevation` property. If `elevation` is removed, circle with `position: 'absolute'` is working properly.

Any ideas how to use elevation and position View absolute?

My Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';


export default class Position extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 25 }}>
        <View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red', elevation: 3}}/>
        <View style={styles.circle}><Text>HELLO</Text></View>  
    </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    top: 30,
    borderRadius: 100,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }    
});
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Found resolution by adding `elevation` to circle `View` as well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I guess the best way to deal with it is to use photoshop or xd or something like that to give the bottom view the elevation look....wish there was a better way

Answer (score 0):

Add shadow to circle as well and increase shadow level of circle by 1. So in your case add elevation 4 for circle.