# zIndex doesot work on Card of native-base - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I'm using `native-base`.
this is my code:

```
                     <View style={{width:'100%',height:45}}>
                      <Card style={{position:'absolute',zIndex:90,paddingTop: 0, marginRight:10,width: '100%', alignSelf: 'center',borderRadius:10,padding:10,height:45 }}>
                        <CardItem style={{ position:'absolute', zIndex:1,backgroundColor: '#fff', height: 45, width: '100%', paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0, justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onClickSubs(sub)} style={{height:'100%',width:'100%'}}>
                            <Text onPress={() => this.onClickSubs(sub)} style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 16, color: colorConstants.GRAY_LIGHT_COLOR }}>{sub.title}</Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        </CardItem>
                      </Card>
                      <View style={{position:'absolute',zIndex:999,right:0,width:20,height:20,borderRadius:10,borderWidth:2,borderColor:'#fff',backgroundColor:colorConstants.PRIMARY_COLOR,alignSelf:'center',justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
                      </View> //circle view

                      </View>
```

but my circle view is background of `Card`:

Comment: did you try elevation? for example elevation: 2

Comment: I think the problem is elevation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821016/react-native-elevation-and-position-absolute

Comment: @S.M_Emamian it's not a problem of zIndex

Comment: yes, the problem is `elevation`. when you use `elevation` property and if you have a `zIndex` property, you should use `elevation` for all element's of inside of parent element. I think this is a bug and I reported it to github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **elevation** value in your circle view style

```
        <View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            zIndex: 999,
            right: 0,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            borderRadius: 10,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "#fff",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            alignSelf: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            elevation:3  <-----------elevation in circle view---------
          }}
        />
```

### without elevation

[image]

### with elevation

[image]

Comment: yes, the problem is `elevation`. when you use `elevation` property and if you have a `zIndex` property, you should use `elevation` for all element's of inside of parent element. I think this is a bug and I reported it to github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23173